# Knockout.JS declaring variable as observable not working correctly

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to declare the variables for some inputs as observables but it's not working properly. The form loads properly, however when I submit the form the values are just javascript code.

Here is the form

```
<div data-bind="visible: shippingBillingContact()">
    <table border="1">
        <tr><td>Full Name</td><td><input type="text" data-bind='value: fullName'/></td>
        <tr><td>Address Line 1</td><td><input type="text" data-bind='value: addressLine1'/></td>
        <tr><td>Address Line 2</td><td><input type="text" data-bind='value: addressLine2'/></td>
        <tr><td>City</td><td><input type="text" data-bind='value: city'/></td>
        <tr><td>State</td><td><input type="text" data-bind='value: state'/></td>
        <tr><td>ZIP</td><td><input type="text" data-bind='value: ZIP'/></td>
        <tr><td>Email</td><td><input type="text" data-bind='value: email'/></td>
    </table>
    <button data-bind="click: back">Go Back</button>
    <br>
    <button data-bind="click: submitOrder">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Here's the viewmodel where I declare the variables. No other processing is done to them

```
function EntryViewModel(fullName, addressLine1, addressLine2, city, state, ZIP, email) {
    var self = this;
    self.newItem = ko.observable("");
    //fullName through email are the items giving me problems
    self.fullName = ko.observable();
    self.addressLine1 = ko.observable();
    self.addressLine2 = ko.observable();
    self.city = ko.observable();
    self.state = ko.observable();
    self.ZIP = ko.observable();
    self.email = ko.observable();

    //these are used to show/hide divs (work properly)
    self.cartContents = ko.observable(true);
    self.shippingBillingContact = ko.observable(false);
    self.orderComplete = ko.observable(false);

    //start the array with some items
    self.itemNumbers = ko.observableArray([

    ]);

    //the values for ItemNumbers, quantities, prices, names are all looked up
    //I omitted this code because it in no way interacts with the customer information

    $.getJSON("/orders/submit_order/" + itemNumbers + "/" + quantities + "/" + prices + "/" + productNames + "/" + self.fullName + "/" + self.addressLine1 + "/" + self.addressLine2 + "/" + self.city + "/" + self.state + "/" + self.ZIP + "/" + self.email,function(data) {
            if(data.check == "success"){
                self.shippingBillingContact(!self.shippingBillingContact()); //hide the shipping form
                self.orderComplete(!self.orderComplete()); //show the order complete form and display the order
            }
            else{
                alert('Price Mismatch. If you believe this was an error please re-add the items');
                self.cartContents(!self.cartContents());
                self.shippingBillingContact(!self.shippingBillingContact()); //hide the shipping form
            }
        });
```

So the URL shows something like this. As you can see the items information is displayed just fine, but the customer information is a bunch of javascript.

```
orders/submit_order/1/1/5.99/ItemA/function%20d()%7Bif(0%3Carguments.length)%7Bif(!d.equalityComparer%7C%7C!d.equalityComparer(c,arguments[0]))d.H(),c=arguments[0],d.G();return%20this%7Db.r.Wa(d);return%20c%7D/function%20d()%7Bif(0%3Carguments.length)%7Bif(!d.equalityComparer%7C%7C!d.equalityComparer(c,arguments[0]))d.H(),c=arguments[0],d.G();return%20this%7Db.r.Wa(d);return%20c%7D/function%20d()%7Bif(0%3Carguments.length)%7Bif(!d.equalityComparer%7C%7C!d.equalityComparer(c,arguments[0]))d.H(),c=arguments[0],d.G();return%20this%7Db.r.Wa(d);return%20c%7D/function%20d()%7Bif(0%3Carguments.length)%7Bif(!d.equalityComparer%7C%7C!d.equalityComparer(c,arguments[0]))d.H(),c=arguments[0],d.G();return%20this%7Db.r.Wa(d);return%20c%7D/function%20d()%7Bif(0%3Carguments.length)%7Bif(!d.equalityComparer%7C%7C!d.equalityComparer(c,arguments[0]))d.H(),c=arguments[0],d.G();return%20this%7Db.r.Wa(d);return%20c%7D/function%20d()%7Bif(0%3Carguments.length)%7Bif(!d.equalityComparer%7C%7C!d.equalityComparer(c,arguments[0]))d.H(),c=arguments[0],d.G();return%20this%7Db.r.Wa(d);return%20c%7D/function%20d()%7Bif(0%3Carguments.length)%7Bif(!d.equalityComparer%7C%7C!d.equalityComparer(c,arguments[0]))d.H(),c=arguments[0],d.G();return%20this%7Db.r.Wa(d);return%20c%7D
```

I also tried the following variations but neither worked

```
self.fullName = ko.observable("");
self.fullName = ko.observable(fullName);
```

Comment: You should call observables as function: self.city() instead of self.city

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must call observables as function: self.city() instead of self.city ...

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that, thanks. It's been a while since I've worked with knockout...